# passing variables into python from html using json

Tags: python, html, django, json

I'm new to html/javascript and Python in general, and have been working on a Django project for a class.  I'm supposed to create an html page that will allow the user to choose attributes to keep, and then pass these variables into a python program that will filter out the relevant attributes from files.  The python work has been finished, and only the html interface needs to be completed.  I understand that this will require the use of json to pass values into the .py, but have been unable to figure out how to do so.

I guess my exact question would be:  Given a page that allows you to check attributes to keep, how would I pass said attributes as variables into a python method?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I have tried to make my own simple Django server to get the gist of how data is passed between files, but have not been able to understand how to pass the json object between file types.  Since I've never touched html before, it has been hard for me to understand how to manipulate variables within it.  I guess what I would really like to know is how json (specifically jquery's json) is passed to and from files.

Answer (score 0):

You keep referring to "passing between files", but I think that terminology is confusing and possibly wrong. The file types of the source code for various components is of no concern to your issue. What you want to focus on is this process:

1. Create an html web page that contains a form, representing the data you are working with.
2. When the form is submitted, the form contents will be sent to your server.
3. Your server is django, implying that your html page is a template, implying that the template will be served from a django view method.
4. The django view method can both serve the fresh template page (when the request.method is not "POST"), and accept and handle the form (when the request.method is "POST"), and redisplay the updated form contents.
5. Your django form will keep persistant data in either a session, or in your database. The initial view of your template will show the current attribute values for your object. Results from the form will modify these values and then redisplay the form.

This question is far too broad to give you any more specifics than this. But, I recommend reading a basic django tutorial on how to process forms and templates. You really only need a single view, and a single template file.

To be honest, I don't see JSON being necessary anywhere in this process unless you are trying to make a more advanced API. There is no reason to submit JSON when your form can just submit the normal www form encoded format. JSON would only be necessary if you were writing an API. If that is the case, then your html form would have to first serialize to json, and then submit via an ajax request to your django server, which would be expecting an incoming json request.